# Zookeeper: is updater supposed to receive events for it's own updates?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a single zookeeper client host.

1. The host creates an ephemeral znode
2. The host set a data-watch by calling `getData` for this znode.
3. The host calls `setData` for this znode.

**Is the host supposed to receive a data-changed-event in this case?**

I've tested it and there is no event. So I'm trying to figure out is it correct behavior or a bug in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should receive events in case of its own updates.

[image: See this screenshot]

Comment: Finally I figured out, there was no events because I always updated my znode with the same value.

Comment: @Jofsey : Nice that you figured it out :)